# Jquery simple slide menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get this panel menu to work. I've been working on it for hours without any success. I have it partially working. See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rs2QK/3471/).

What I'm trying to do is:

1. When you click target 1, target 2, target 3 links. The div holding these links should slide out. Right now, it is only being covered and hidden by the next div that is sliding in. I would like it to slide out first to the left, and then have the next div slide in after.
2. After clicking one of the target links. Then when clicking "main menu" link, make the "target" box below (green, red, yellow boxes) slide out from right to left and have the "target menu" the one that loads initially, slide in from the left. Right now, I can't get that "main menu" link to do anything. It should show the initial target menu when clicked.

I know there is a lot of right and left stuff in there. But I wanted to be as specific as possible. I'm not really concerned about the direction of the slide. I am more concerned just to make it work first.

```
<div class="main-menu"><a href="#target0">Main Menu Link</a>
</div> 

<div id="right" id="target0">
This is the Target Menu<br />
<a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
<a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
<a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>

<div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:green">Target 1</div>
<div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:red">Target 2</div>
<div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:yellow">Target 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just realized I am probably missing the class="panel" on the main menu link. However, it still doesn't work once I add this. Please help.

Comment: #right div has two times the declaration of id property. Each element has an unique Id and there can't be two elements with the same I'd

Answer (score 0):

The #target0 is your entire element (it contains target1 target2 and target3)

You should break it out on its own:

```
<div class="main-menu"><a href="#target0" class="panel">Main Menu Link</a>
</div> 
<div id="right" id="main">
    <div id="target0" class="panel active">This is the Target Menu<br />
        <a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
        <a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
        <a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:green">Target 1</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:red">Target 2</div>
    <div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:yellow">Target 3</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: 
To make the gray block slide, you should add your Panel class to it (I also added the active class so it displays by default). You'll just need to style it

```
div.panel.active {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/rs2QK/3474/ Now all I need to do is make the gray container slide in and out.

Comment: Updated the code: http://jsfiddle.net/L7v0w96s/  Just needs some css styling to fix the discrepencies (its displaying in the middle of the box)

Comment: It's getting really close! I just need the target links (actually the entire gray div box) to slide out once a target link is clicked. Right now it just stays where it is and is being covered by the next div that slides in.

Comment: Oh, I missed your last comment. Let me try to slide the gray box.

Comment: Just changed some of the CSS. Its working now! Same fiddle, I updated it

Comment: Thanks Bryan. It seems the gray box is still not sliding out. It look like it is only sliding in. Or maybe I am looking at the wrong fiddle?